# The underlying connection was closed The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I facing an issue while using entity framework when using the below query

**Controller**

```
TestPlanService.TestPlanServiceClient svclient = new TestPlanService.TestPlanServiceClient();

            try
            {
                return svclient.GetTestPlans().ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string exmess = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
```

**Query**

```
    using (DataModelContainer db = new DataModelContainer())
                {
                    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                    var query = (from c in db.TestPlans.Include(x => x.TestPoints)
                                 select c);
                    var result = query.ToList();
                    return result;
})
```

In the above code though i am able to return the list from the db with all the child elements loaded

**The model is as follows**

```
public partial class TestPlan
    {
        public TestPlan()
        {
            this.TestPoints = new HashSet<TestPoint>();
        }

        public int TestPlanId { get; set; }
        public string TestPlanName { get; set; }
        public int TestPlanTypeId { get; set; }
        public int RiskTierID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TestPoint> TestPoints { get; set; }
        public virtual TestPlanType TestPlanType { get; set; }
        public virtual RiskTierMaster RiskTierMaster { get; set; }
    }

public partial class TestPoint
    {
        public TestPoint()
        {
            this.TestPlans = new HashSet<TestPlan>();
        }

        public int TestPointId { get; set; }
        public string TestPointName { get; set; }
        public int TestMethodId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PassThreshold { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FailThreshold { get; set; }
        public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual TestMethod TestMethod { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TestPlan> TestPlans { get; set; }
        public virtual OrganizationMaster OrganizationMaster { get; set; }
    }
```

A test plan can have multiple test points.
I am able to return the result from service but unfortunately on the controller side it throw as error as
"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly"

Let me know if someone has any solution for this.

Comment: You are using WCF at the server? Can you show us the method signature of the wcf method?

Comment: Typically when I see this it is because of a serialization error. Check your windows application logs (on the server). You might have more information there. Typically there I find there is an issue with my `DataContract`. Assuming of course you are using WCF Soap.

Comment: Hi Wouter,
This is the interface

    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface ITestPlanService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<MMM.Lumos.Entities.TestPlan> GetTestPlans();             
    }

Comment: This error is basically when i am using .Include() of the Entity frameowrk. Otherwise it will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aron,

You were right i suppose it was because of serialization error.
Well for the other who are searching for this issue, this is what helped me out.

In my Entity model .edmx file where the .tt files are generated just add two lines of code as below. This should be done for all the entities within that model

I have applied it to one of my class as below,

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;    
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class TestPlanType
{
    public TestPlanType()
    {
        this.TestPlans = new HashSet<TestPlan>();
    }

    public int TestPlanTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TestPlanTypeName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TestPlan> TestPlans { get; set; }
}
```

[this article helped me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee853286%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)